# Apache Superset breaks on add new chart : Object of type 'function' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, flask, apache-superset

I have setup superset as per the documentation from the official site. I am able to create charts and dashboards from the Explore option in SQLLab, but getting the following error when I try to create a chart from `New +` button on the home page.

Python version: 3.6.3

Superset version : 0.38.0

Breaking URL : `/chart/add`

```
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 109, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/views/chart/views.py", line 71, in add
    "superset/add_slice.html", bootstrap_data=json.dumps(payload)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'function' is not JSON serializable
```